# How to access a value in a map (across a list of maps) and convert those values into list FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get a number out of a list of maps and sum it's values. I'm think I'm stuck on the line of code where I define where "timerSec" is in the map to put it in a list before summing it. I keep getting a "Class 'UserAttempt' has no instance method '[]'." error

I've verified a list of UserAttempts is returned from firebase. Each UserAttempt contains an IdealPosition node which contains the "timerSec" in value. From the below results I would expect a result of 13.

```
-UserAttempt1 (level 1 node)
--IdealPosition (level 2 node)
---timerSec: 3 (int value)
-UserAttempt2 (level 1 node)
--IdealPosition (level 2 node)
---timerSec: 4 (int value)
-UserAttempt3 (level 1 node)
--IdealPosition (level 2 node)
---timerSec: 6 (int value)
```

I call the function getUserAttempts() (which I verify in the debugger populates _userAttempts with the list of userAttempts). On the next line in the following function I can't seem to figure out how to locate timerSec in the userAttempt map to put in a list to sum. I keep get the getting a "Class 'UserAttempt' has no instance method '[]'." error.

```
Future<int> getTotalAttemptTime() async {
  var result;
  var _userAttempts = await getUserAttempts();
  timerSecList = _userAttempts.map<int>((m) => m['UserAttempt']['idealPosition']['timerSec'] as int).toList();
  result = timerSecList.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element);
  print("OMG!!!! $result");
  return result;
}
```

I've also seen other examples that I hacked up and couldn't get working.

```
_userAttempts.entries.map((e) => timerSecList.add(e.value));
_userAttempts.map.forEach((_userAttempt.idealPosition.timerSec) => as List);
```

Here's where I am at in the code

```
class UserAttemptsManager extends ChangeNotifier{
  final _fsCrudManager = locator<FstoreCrudManagerUserSession>();

  List<UserAttempt> _userAttempts = [];
  UserAttempt _userAttempt;
  List<IdealPosition> _idealPositions;
  IdealPosition _idealPosition;
  List<int> timerSecList = [];

  getUserAttempts() async {
    _userAttempts =  await _fsCrudManager.fetchPositions();
    return _userAttempts;
  }

  Future<int> getTotalAttemptTime() async {
   var result;
   var _userAttempts = await getUserAttempts();
   timerSecList = _userAttempts.map<int>((m) => m['UserAttempt']['idealPosition']['timerSec'] as int).toList();
  result = timerSecList.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element);
   print("OMG!!!! $result");
   return result;
  }

}
```

Here's the relevant classes

```
class UserAttempt {
  String id;
  double score;
  DateTime dateTime;
  IdealPosition idealPosition;
  List<UserAttemptItem> userAttemptLog;

  UserAttempt({this.id, this.dateTime,this.userAttemptLog, this.score, this.idealPosition});

  // from firestore to map
  factory UserAttempt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, String id){
    //var _id = id;
    if (json['userAttemptLog'] != null) {
      var userAttemptLogObjsJson = json['userAttemptLog'] as List;
      List<UserAttemptItem> _userAttemptLog = userAttemptLogObjsJson.map((userAttemptLogJson) => UserAttemptItem.fromJson(userAttemptLogJson, id)).toList();

      return UserAttempt(
        id: id = id,
        score: json['score'],
        dateTime: json['dateTime'].toDate(),
        idealPosition: IdealPosition.fromMap(json['idealPosition'], id),
        userAttemptLog: _userAttemptLog
      );
    } else {
      return UserAttempt(
        id: id = id,
        dateTime: json['dateTime'].toDate(),
        score: json['score'],
        idealPosition: IdealPosition.fromMap(json['idealPosition'], id),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.id}, ${this.userAttemptLog} }';
  }

  // to firestore
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    //final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    List<Map> _userAttemptLog = this.userAttemptLog != null ? this.userAttemptLog.map((i) => i.toJson()).toList() : null;
    Map idealPosition = this.idealPosition != null ? this.idealPosition.toJson() : null;

    return {
      //'id': id,
      'score': score,
      'dateTime': DateTime.now(),
      'idealPosition': idealPosition,
      'userAttemptLog': _userAttemptLog,

    };
  }
}
```

also one for the idealPosition (leaving out the UserAttemptLog for now)

```
class IdealPosition {
  String id;
  String type;
  String name;
  int timerSec;
  int orientation;

  IdealPosition({
    this.id,
    this.type,
    this.name,
    this.timerSec,
    this.orientation,
  });

  // From firebase
  IdealPosition.fromMap(Map snapshot, String id)
      :
        id = id ?? '',
        type = snapshot['type'] ?? 'undefined',
        name = snapshot['name'] ?? 'Undefined',
        timerSec = snapshot['timerSec'] ?? 0,
        orientation = snapshot['orientation'] ?? 2;

  // To firebase
  toJson() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "timerSec": timerSec,
      "type": type,
      "orientation": orientation,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed `var _userAttempts = await getUserAttempts();` to this `List<UserAttempt> _userAttempts = await getUserAttempts();' and got rid of the error after making the suggested changes below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final timerSecSum = _userAttempts.map((m) => m.idealPosition.timerSec).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I see you have added the second function to do the summing . I'll be able to take this pattern use it elsewhere. Great to see how that works and how clean it is. Also please note I don't have the reputation to select an answer as an answer (or really do anything) yet.

Comment: Had a chance to swap the line out and got the following error `type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(UserAttempt) => int' of 'f'`

Comment: Remove <int> before map

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
   timerSecList = _userAttempts.map<int>((m) => m['UserAttempt']['idealPosition']['timerSec'] as int).toList();
```

to this:

```
timerSecList = _userAttempts.map<int>((m) => m.idealPosition.timerSec).toList();
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I couldn't get that part right. Thank you so much. I'll be able to try it out later tonight. Also please note I don't have the reputation to select an answer as an answer (or really do anything)

Comment: Had a chance to swap the line out and got the following error `type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(UserAttempt) => int' of 'f'`

Comment: Remove <int> before map